# Getting the output of a msqli prepared statement as a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am beginning using prepared statements:

```
($stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE token=?'))
|| fail('MySQL prepare', $db->error);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $token)
|| fail('MySQL bind_param', $db->error);
$stmt->execute()
|| fail('MySQL execute', $db->error);
$stmt->close();
```

The statement returns an email address, and I was wondering if it is possible to convert the desired email address into a string for further use in PHP? Which is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you been through the MySQLi manual? This is the purpose of [`bind_result()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_result($email);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $email;
```

Comment: Don't forget to `fetch()`.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy... with [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM users WHERE token=?');
$stmt->execute(array($token));
$desired_string = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

note the amount of code required